# toLowerCase() strange behaviour

Tags: java

toLowerCase() converts the string to lowercase but when i use it in a logic it gives bizarre results. I can do the logic in some other way without even using toLowerCase() but please tell me what's wrong here

```
char gender = 'M';
System.out.println((gender+"").toLowerCase());          //prints "m"
System.out.println((gender+"").toLowerCase()=="m");     //false

if ((gender+"").toLowerCase()=="m") {
    System.out.println("if it went through loop");
}
```

Comment: Strange part is that you are using == for string comparison instead of equals method

Comment: System.out.println((gender+"").toLowerCase().equals("m")) should be used

Comment: Or `if ((gender+"").toLowerCase().intern()=="m") {
      System.out.println("if it went through loop");
  }` (I don't recommend it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if ((gender+"").toLowerCase().equals("m"))`. You should not use `==` operator to compare the value of `String`. Use `equals()` method instead. Learn [how the comparison of strings with equals and assignment operator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/)

Comment: thanx, i am new to java just recently started

Comment: @user3177212 No issues :) I've made these mistakes too :). You'll get good info in the link.

Comment: oo i should have seen compare strings question i thought there was something wrong with toLowerCase, l'll delete the question

Comment: @user3177212. You don't have to delete the question. It can be useful for others.